# Debug Gradient Computation Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning

I am using a frozen graph to extract features and then want to train a predictor on top to perform some inference.

Unfortunately, the gradients can not be computed and my process is killed with RAM demands >100GB. I have checked several things:

1) Reducing input image sizes or batch sizes is not the problem.

2) I can use intermediate layers of my frozen network (Variant of ResNet) and performan training of my small inference net. But, using the later layers leads to huge memory demands (killed). This confuses me because I keep my network static and there are no trainable variables in the ResNet. Thus, I do not think the gradient should depend on the layer of my frozen net which i extract.

This behavior is unexpected to me. What are ways to debug what causes this huge memory demand when calling sess.run(train_op, feed_dict)?

More information:

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
graph1 = tf.Graph()

graph1.__enter__()

input_tensor = tf.placeholder('float', shape=input_shape, name='image')



# Loading frozen graph and mapping inputs

f = gfile.FastGFile(pb_file, 'rb')
graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
# Parses a serialized binary message into the current message.
graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
f.close()

_ = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def , input_map={'input0': input_tensor})

# Get feature layer
output_feature = 'import/layer3.00/add:0'
feature_tensor =  graph.get_tensor_by_name(output_feature)


output = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(feature_tensor, 100, scope='readout_network)


def batch_data(batches):
    # e.g. batches = [[1,2], [3,4]] 

    for batch in batches:
            images = [stimuli.stimuli[n] for n in batch]

            xs = []
            ys = []

            for i, n in enumerate(batch):
                xs.append(this_cache['xs'][n])
                ys.append(this_cache['ys'][n])

            yield prepare_input(images, xs, ys)

loss = ...

params = slim.get_variables_to_restore(include=['readout_network'])

train_opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001).minimize(loss, var_list=params)


for feed_dict in batch_data:

    sess.run(train_op, feed_dict = feed_dict)
```

Comment: As a wild guess, not to use feed_dict at all. Use data API instead . But it would be helpful if you provide some code. Especially data input pipeline

Comment: @Sharky I have updated my question.

Comment: Are your images stored locally?

Comment: Yes, they are - why do you think calling sess.run() is a problem here?